# Ajax call loop only one object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following ajax call but instead to show me all objects it shows me only the last object from json file. Why is this?

Ajax Call

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var data = 'data.json';
  var url = 'http://localhost:8888/';
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState === 4 ) {
      if(ajax.status === 200){
        callback(ajax.responseText);
      } else if(ajax.status === 400) {
        console.warn('404');
      } else {
        console.warn('bad' + ajax.responseText);
      }
    }
  };
  ajax.open('GET', url+data, true);
  ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
  ajax.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  ajax.send(data);
```

JSON

```
{
    "video": {
    "mp4": "http://localhost:8888/500x.mp4", 
    "webm": "http://localhost:8888/500x.webm", 
    "title": "video1" },

    "video": {
    "mp4": "http://localhost:8888/dodge.mp4", 
    "webm": "http://localhost:8888/dodge.webm", 
    "title": "video2" },

    "video": {
    "mp4": "http://localhost:8888/500x.mp4", 
    "webm": "http://localhost:8888/500x.webm", 
    "title": "video3" }
}
```

Callback function where getVideoURL is my Ajax Call Function

```
inject : function(tabId, infos, tab){
    if(doner.activated && infos.status === 'complete' && doner.filters.isYoutubeUrl(tab.url)){
      doner.getVideoUrls(function(data){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{
          code : '!function(e){"use strict";console.debug("starting injection");var t=document.createElement("script");t.src=chrome.extension.getURL("scripts/injectedScript.js"),t.onload=function(){this.parentNode.removeChild(this)},(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(t);var o=document.getElementById("extAdd");o&&o.parentNode&&(console.log("removing",o),o.parentNode.removeChild(o));var n=document.createElement("iframe");document.getElementById("player-api").setAttribute("style","padding:0;");n.id="extAdd",n.setAttribute("style","border-style:none;-webkit-appearance:none;border:0;outline:none;"),n.className="html5-video-player el-detailpage ps-null hide-info-bar autohide-controls-aspect autohide-controls-fullscreen autominimize-progress-bar-non-aspect ad-created endscreen-created captions-created captions-loaded ytp-block-autohide paused-mode",n.setAttribute("allowfullscreen","true"),n.src=chrome.extension.getURL("iframe/iframe.html?id="+e);var d=document.getElementById("player-api");d.insertBefore(n,d.childNodes[0]);}("' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data)) + '");',
          runAt: 'document_start'
        }, function(){
          // get the popup and increase the watched value
          chrome.storage.local.get({ 'watched' : 0 },function(item){
            console.log(item);
            chrome.storage.local.set({'watched':item.watched + 1});
          });

          console.log('injected');
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is there in `callback`

Comment: Because you're using `video` for every key in the object.  You cannot have duplicate keys in JS objects.

Comment: Try wrapping your `ajax.responseText` in a `JSON.parse()` - Untested so I wouldn't know if it works

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is an object, and the property `video` is declared three times. So the last declaration stay in the memory.

Maybe you should change your JSON structure and use an array :

```
[
    {
        "video": {
            "mp4": "http://localhost:8888/500x.mp4",
            "webm": "http://localhost:8888/500x.webm",
            "title": "video1"
        }
    },

    {
        "video": {
            "mp4": "http://localhost:8888/dodge.mp4",
            "webm": "http://localhost:8888/dodge.webm",
            "title": "video2"
        }
    },

    {
        "video": {
            "mp4": "http://localhost:8888/500x.mp4",
            "webm": "http://localhost:8888/500x.webm",
            "title": "video3"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I am using this way because I am using video.js and that is looking for that "video"

Comment: @FlapJack, can you point to the place in the documentation where it mentions that because I can't find it.

Comment: @Andy I don't know where actually but if I change that "video" or remove it will become null so it can't be accessed.

Comment: `p = function() {
            window.clearTimeout(k);
            c(j, e, e.response || e.responseText)
        };` this is from video.js

Comment: @FlapJack It's not what I'm looking for, where is the declation of the `callback` function you use ?

Comment: you don't need to declare it somewhere. it is used to return data as a string. So it GET data from data.json and then it should give the response as a string

Comment: @FlapJack, ok I always used jQuery for AJAX calls. What do you do then with `ajax.responseText` ?

Comment: It showing the videos from my data.json but instead to show me all videos from there it shows me only the last one

Comment: @FlapJack I updated my post. Could you try with the new JSON structure ?

Comment: I've tried this way but it has something to do with that "video"

Comment: To be fair the original code is looking like this `var data = 'badadtoken=DDIxhpyyKbKC6IXxQ8jn35h57obttZ0G';
  var url = 'http://www.dandad.org/badad/';` and with this is showing multiple videos on each page refresh with my one is showing the same one every time